# Getting message status queued while sending SMS using Twilio

Tags: spring-boot, twilio, sms

In my Spring boot project I have integrated Twilio SMS API to sent SMS. Both To and From numbers are U.S numbers. Although no exception messages are displayed when sending SMS, the message is not recieved by the recipient. When checking message.getStaus() it shows queued.

I attempted to find a solutions on the Twilio website and found that A2P 10DLC registration is required to send SMS in the US. However I am unable to locate the process for completing A2P 10DLC registration.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.